# Как спарсить значения в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Имеется строчка: `Rushka\n├❤️566/500  ⚔️778 197\n├500 | 1\n├110 | ‍♂️250\n├9/19`
Нужно спарсить значения: ник (), здоровья (❤️), урон(⚔️) и пр.
Написал вот так:

```py
text = "Rushka\n├❤️566/500  ⚔️778 197\n├500 | 1\n├110 | ‍♂️250\n├9/19"
param = re.findall(r'^(\w+)\b', text)
print(param)

symbols = ["", "⚔️", ""]
for value in text:
    print("value: " + value)
    for symbol in symbols:
        print("Symbol: " + symbol)
        print(re.findall(r'^{}(/w+)\b'.format(symbol), value))
```

Заметил, что в регулярное выражение в последней строчке не работает.
Почему оно не работает? Как лучше спарсить все значения?
p.s по итогу нужно занести значения в БД
p.s.s значения, которые имеют формат x/y (например, здоровье (❤️566/500)) нужно брать второе значение, то бишь y.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: слэш в другую сторону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать словарь, если уместно использование пиктограмм в качестве ключей:

```py
import re
for c in '❤️⚔️‍♂️':
    print(c, '\t', c.encode(encoding='unicode_escape'))
print()

text = ["Rushka\n├❤️566/500  ⚔️778 197\n├500 | 1\n├110 | ‍♂️250\n├9/19",
        "BrainRTP\n├ —\n├Мегатонна\n├❤️14/14 | 0% | ⚔️18 | 4\n├7 | 3\n├5 | ‍♂️6\n├5/5 | 0\n├Нью-Рино\n├Портупея +3 100%\n├Вязаная шапка +1 66%\n├Мачете\n+11⚔️ 22%\n├0\n├6560\n└Нейтральный",]
params = []
rx = re.compile(r'(?m)(|❤️|⚔️|||||\U0001f938\U0001f3fd\u200d\u2642\ufe0f|)\s*(?:\d+/)?(\w+)')
for t in text:
    params.append(dict(rx.findall(t)))
    for p in params[-1]:
        print(p, ':\t', params[-1][p])
    print()
```

**Вывод:**

```
   b'\\U0001f464'
❤    b'\\u2764'
️    b'\\ufe0f'
⚔    b'\\u2694'
️    b'\\ufe0f'
   b'\\U0001f6e1'
   b'\\U0001f4aa'
   b'\\U0001f3af'
   b'\\U0001f5e3'
   b'\\U0001f938'
   b'\\U0001f3fd'
‍    b'\\u200d'
♂    b'\\u2642'
️    b'\\ufe0f'
   b'\\U0001f50b'

⚔️ :     778
 :     1
 :     19
‍♂️ :    250
 :     110
 :     500
 :     Rushka
 :     197
❤️ :     500

⚔️ :     18
 :     3
 :     5
‍♂️ :    6
 :     5
 :     7
 :     BrainRTP
 :     4
❤️ :     14
```

Демо на [Rextester](https://rextester.com/WDXHEG27439).
Объяснение регулярного выражения на [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/dMMxfS/1).

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Если не сложно, не могли бы вы подсказать как отсеять знак "" в строчке:
text = "BrainRTP\n├ —\n├Мегатонна\n├❤️14/14 | 0% | ⚔️18 | 4\n├7 | 3\n├5 | ‍♂️6\n├5/5 | 0\n├Нью-Рино\n├Портупея +3 100%\n├Вязаная шапка +1 66%\n├Мачете\n+11⚔️ 22%\n├0\n├6560\n└Нейтральный"
т.к при попытке спарсить эту строчку он идет ни сверху вниз, а снизу вверх при этом берет значение "урон  (⚔️)" не из положенного места и вместе с символом "".

Comment: Ответ скорректирован. Возможны ли какие-то еще варианты входной строки, кроме уже приведенных?

Comment: Да, есть еще вот такой вариант строки, но, думаю, это нужно сделать другой регуляркой: 
https://pastebin.com/gdu30Ch4   Опять же, парсить те же самые значения
нашел решение. Например, с "", в выражении использовать "Выносливость:"

Comment: Все-же появилась проблема с иконками и словарем. Как лучше сделать используя юникод?https://pastebin.com/iz9FwtNw

Comment: Дополнил ответ использованием [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) с параметром [`unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

Comment: Не получается. Как я могу с Вами связаться вне stackoverflow?

Comment: Можно попробовать https://chat.stackoverflow.com